# how to call gdal module in python

Tags: gdal, pyqgis

I confused that how to call python gdal module in the path such as gdal_calc.py(C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py)
a test code below,but it don't work.

```
import os
os.sys('python C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py -A D:\temp\m2000049.tif -B D:\temp\m2000057.tif --outfile=D:\temp\result.tif --calc=(A+B)')
```

refect the error:

> os.sys('python C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py -A
>   D:\temp\m2000049.tif -B D:\temp\m2000057.tif
>   --outfile=D:\temp\result.tif --calc=(A+B)')
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 os.sys('python C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py -A D:\temp\m2000049.tif -B D:\temp\m2000057.tif
>   --outfile=D:\temp\result.tif --calc=(A+B)')
>
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Might not help but try replacing all backward slashes with a single forward slash.

Comment: Try with subprocess.call like this subprocess.call('gdal_calc.py -A file1 -B file2 --outfile=output.tif --calc=(A+B)', shell=True). Add gdal_calc.py path to environment variable afterwards no need to give full path.

Comment: the problem has been solved. after installed winpython environ, it also need to add python path to windows environmental path variable. ps:it looks like that tif path need double quotation mark.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try below, I think because inputs not parsed correctly :

```
import os
os.sys('python "C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_calc.py" -A "D:\temp\m2000049.tif" -B "D:\temp\\m2000057.tif" --outfile="D:\temp\\result.tif" --calc="(A+B)" ')
```